# How can I tell my counter to stop incrementing when it has reached a specific amount?

Tags: react-native, hook, setinterval

I'm trying to implement a counter that stops when it has reached a certain amount, but what I have at the moment doesn't stop. It seems to increment continuously; why is this? Does it have something to do with when or how many times `useEffect` is executed?

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter < 10) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
      }, incrementRate);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Circular progress bar</Text>
      <Text>{`${counter}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `useState` functional updater inside your effect, which means it will use its previous state to increment the count, which is correct but it gives you a false perception that the effect is working correctly. Your mental model for how `useEffect` works needs to a shift a little, it's really common, so much so Dan Abramov has written an [extensive article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#what-happens-when-dependencies-lie) on `useEffect` with this exact scenario.

The quick fix is to add `counter` to your dependency array, so that you can tell React its changed, so it will no longer skip updating the effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (counter < 10) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
    }, incrementRate);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }
}, [counter]);
```

It's not the cleanest approach as you'll clear the interval and create a new one each time the effect runs.

You could however use `setTimeout` instead and avoid the clearing of intervals altogether.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (counter < 10) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
    }, incrementRate);
  }
}, [counter]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!